# WinJS handle suspended state

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I've a little issue here and I need some help. I'm developing a windows 8 Metro App using HTML and JavaScript and since I've migrated from the Consumer Preview to the Release Preview it seems I can't change the state of my application to suspended when I'm debugging it.

The problem is when I'm clicking on the button "Suspended" in the debug bar the application state changes from "Running" to "Not responding".

Therefore I wasn't able to find a solution to debug my solution and especially debug my app to test if my code called by the `app.oncheckpoint` function behaves well.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked OK.
Can you give more details?
Which template are you using?
Have you tried with a new project from that template?

There might be something you are doing which is causing this.

Comment: Hi, I'm using a grid application template. I've tried to create a new project (gridapp) and the result is the same when I click the suspended button in Visual Studio (VS 2012 RC btw) the application goes to "Not Responding" instead of "Suspended"

Comment: I see that also, but debugging does work if I set a breakpoint in app.oncheckpoint..